# Proving that the following sequence of real numbers converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-writing

> I need to prove that the following sequence converges
>   $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{2n+1}{5n+4}=\frac{2}{5}$

My proof is the following:

Choose $\varepsilon \gt 0$

Let $N=\lfloor\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\rfloor +1$. Then for all $ n\gt N $ , 
$|\frac{2n+1}{5n+4}-\frac{2}{5}| = \frac{3}{5(5n+4)} < \frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{N} < \varepsilon$

Is this right?

Comment: correct I think!

Comment: It looks alright to me, but a bit more detail on the inequalities wouldnt hurt

Comment: Why not using the ratio of derivatives of numerator and denominator?